# Elasticsearch TransportError(400, 'mapper_parsing_exception')

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-elasticsearch

I have some Python code where I am trying to parse some files into AWS ES.  Below is the code:

```
import re
import elasticsearch
import itertools
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection, helpers
from boto3 import client, logging, s3, Session

access_key = 'accesskey'
secret_key = 'secretkey'
bucket = 'bucket'
pattern = '(\d{4}[-]\d{2}[-]\d{2})\s+(\d{2}[:]\d{2}[:]\d{2})\s+(\d{1,3}[.]\d{1,3}[.]\d{1,3}[.]\d{1,3})\s+([GET|PUT|POST]+)\s+([^\s]+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+([^\s]+)\s+(\".*?\")\s+(\".*?\")'
folder = 'subfolder/'
host = 'host'
index_name = 'test_index'

es = Elasticsearch(
    hosts = host,
    connection_class = RequestsHttpConnection,
    port = 443,
    use_ssl = True,
    verify_certs = False)

request_body = {
    'settings': {
        'number_of_shards': 5,
        'number_of_relicas': 0
    },
    'mappings': {
        'logs': {
            'properties': {
                'date': { 'type': 'date', 'format': 'YYYY-MM-DD' },
                'time': { 'type': 'string' },
                'client_ip': { 'type': 'ip' },
                'method': { 'type': 'string' },
                'request': { 'type': 'string' },
                'status_code': { 'type': 'integer' },
                'bytes': { 'type': 'integer' },
                'time_taken': { 'type': 'integer' },
                'referrer': { 'type': 'string' },
                'user_agent': { 'type': 'string' },
                'cookie': { 'type': 'string' }
            }
        }
    }
}

if es.indices.exists('test_index'):
    print(index_name + 'Exists')

else:
    res = es.indices.create(index = index_name, ignore = [400, 404], body = request_body, request_timeout = 30)

session = Session(
    aws_access_key_id = access_key,
    aws_secret_access_key = secret_key,
    region_name = 'region')

s3 = session.resource('s3')
bucket_name = s3.Bucket(bucket)
data = [obj for obj in list(bucket_name.objects.filter(Prefix=folder)) if obj.key != folder]
bulk_data = []

for obj in data:
    body = obj.get()['Body'].read().decode('ISO-8859-1')
    match = re.compile(pattern)
    for line in body.splitlines():
        if not line.startswith('#'):
            result = match.search(line)
            x = 1
            if result is not None:
                for i in range(11):
                    es.index(index = index_name, doc_type = 'logs', body = result.group(x))
                    x += 1
```

However, I continue to get the error:

```
TransportError(400, 'mapper_parsing_exception')
```

This occurs on the index line.  I have checked the data and it looks like my data is being read correctly.  Here is an example of a document that I am trying to index.

```
#Version: 1.0
#Fields: date time cs-ip cs-method cs-uri sc-status sc-bytes time-taken cs(Referer) cs(User-Agent) cs(Cookie)
2016-06-14  18:20:07    1.1.1.1 GET /origin.com/products/PublishingImages/file.png  200 10915   1   "http://www.referrer.com/CategoryPage.aspx?"    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0)" "ASP.NET_SessionId=yjumie0ar12dl; __SessionCookie=7FKbuqkC6pmz2ZKewLVMAjOtKTbLpb8zK8j0TCr+U; __CSALastPageName=XCOaCvdhusg==; __CSALastHierarchy=L7ATLEuRZmXj3ddzXRPF7BVVZFzs=; __CSALastReportSuiteName=0eWICfQzEtcnfMSQ==; __CSARedirectTags=ABOcOdYBWK/O5Rw==; pck=0aa46f231-abc9-cc8d12f4b2d9; __CSCookie=RVqW7dLcpb4QVYDUPoADt5vqtK0oo9QKniVXlY0O83Cet4n73Fah5UvdTzbfayAEgnHsTch/OrCOSTZaK4peWy/1kXq3fX2uHLPbrw4BgXhaZvjRUp4yRhaL+Ug2qcj6pQny6oyot+GPOBP4OgqtbzTZJv7NxykKZHKZRzjYBvBLtbOf9brrzjzeaTbDw7r7SEmVzxQOihmDBGDG0Rn16jC9T8MtbUl3VKz3GojZeLTmYTCXX67oBmnGZPPtV8joGqYrVcHrSj0XKxyeFBluQONFGvEGhw/7TKoshKQfd5oNo7A9eJ+UfEvG51iwT/3ePMd6MvzFMdj+eMuizFcjdas9v+bWH923AYt7rUnb99T8AX6+8cJy0/fj69AkdhG/FTvNQrV05Lpbr5gjL5uy8N4Ng2zsoKMdgrFYalARQNM/8h0i7HhxQyx+OY6PXR0VbTGI=; ETE1=fvClmAi4/MuJaZFB+0Cac7U1k4DgF5ylbBWLfPA5UuABTPG9Xp+KAVSMf3ES0cJm94ok4ZwIQ1Y/AiaX1j7lf6BQpcoI9UwGAe9PUFnpSnxiAlp9I5fSbCJyho3YDa0MoJ9xC7fwwPigfrd7oxdyi8nvCKs5OYcrf0zEAMiMUEMFpaB//Imb3d015qESq0aThMWwhuKwT7C7xyk4Q1mdD0l3kFum4C1g2cbIaNQ5qMJ3M+DJvu7SbjVIAZanGwrt1aZLL/1Eo1MPVEuGmMOj/p6hHtjBc; icxid=1461781512418-308716; gigyaCookieNotification=acknowledged; __PublicSiteRecentSearchesCookie=UeUbHRveUtzmA==; __CSUserIbcIDCookie=dHEe9zrGnQX6OLzOhtqfft1DC571R+670C7m6; __CSUserIbcMonikerCookie=Oiz4bVglhbAzQ==; __qca=P0-455562-1461759; icxid=146512418-3087371016; s_vi=[CS]v1|2B90051D1FEE-4000196D[CE]; s_fid=0C6E0CDA143CF-181DECF8985; ddtLatC=549p52.5p46.5p37p41p55.5p35p105; dtCookie=B66FBB0F22CBB49B863198A2"
2016-06-14  18:20:07    1.1.1.1 GET /origin.com/UI/Core/Images/2c.png   304 204 0   "http://www.referrer.com/CategoryPage.aspx?"    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0)" "ASP.NET_SessionId=yjumie0d5l12dl; __SessionCookie=7FKbuq3luPyu/Tz2ZKewLVMAjOtKTbLpb8zK8j0TCr+U; __CSALastPageName=XCOaFcpXdhusg==; __CSALastHierarchy=L7ATLYBSXZmXj3ddzXRPF7BVVZFzs=; __CSALastReportSuiteName=0eWIC8dcnfMSQ==; __CSARedirectTags=ABOcOxeO5Rw==;  pck=0aa46f23-cc8d12f4b2d9; __CSCookie=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; ETE1=fvClmAi4/MuJaZFB+0Cac7U1k4DPA5UuABTPG9Xp+KAVSMf3ES0cJm94ok4ZwIQ1Y/AiaX1j7lf6BQpcoI9UwGAe9PUFnpSn3YDa0MoJ9xC7fwwPigfrd7oxdyi8nvCKs5OYcrf0zEAMiMUEM//Imb3d015qESq0aThM4W51AmI4EEDdFk2l8aqkDjAE8ZmWwhuKwT7C7xyk4Q1mdD0l3kFum4C1g2cbIaNQ5qMJ3M+DJvu7SbjVIAZanGwrt1aZLL/1Eo1MPVEuGmMOj/p6hHtjBc; icxid=1461418-3071016; gigyaCookieNotification=acknowledged; __PublicSiteRecentSearchesCookie=UeUbHUqUtzmA==; __CSUserIbcIDCookie=dHEe9zrPGNScOhtqfft1DC571R+670C7m6; __CSUserIbcMonikerCookie=Oiz4bVglGrhbAzQ==; __qca=P0-455503562-1461259; icxid=14612418-30873371016; s_vi=[CS]v1|2B917051D1FEE-40001000FA6D[CE]; s_fid=0C6EA0A143CF-1810DF8985; dtPC=-; s_cc=true; dtLatC=54p52.5p46.5p37p4p41p55.5p3p105; dtCookie=B66FBB0F863198A2D45|VVMr1BXU3wx"
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: Captured full error.  Here is output

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to p
arse"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse","caused_by"
:{"type":"not_x_content_exception","reason":"Compressor detection can only be ca
lled on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes"}},"status":400
```

Comment: I don't see any issue, other than the body having single quotes.

Comment: would the single quotes cause issue?

Comment: Actually i'm not sure if that might be an issue. But when i copied request_body and tried in my rest console, it was not able to parse the request_body. changing to double quotes worked. I'm not sure if that will work out here.

Comment: i will try it.  Did you change all single quotes in the mapping to double?  Also, I captured the full exception.  Error: failed to parse. Caused by compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes

Comment: changed all single quotes to double and received same error

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are defining a mapping for 11 fields.  Each of the above will constitute 1 document.  In your processing code below, you break up the header with the regex and then pass each component separately as its own document.

Its breaking cause the mapping of what a document looks like is not what you are passing it:

```
In [1]: body = '2016-06-14  18:20:07    1.1.1.1 GET 

/origin.com/UI/Core/Images/2c.png   304 204 0   "http://www.referrer.com/CategoryPage.aspx?"    "Mozilla/5.0 (Window
   ...: s NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0)" "ASP.NET_SessionId=yjumie0d5l12dl; __SessionCookie=7FKbuq3luPyu/Tz2ZKewLVMAjOtKTbLpb8zK8j0TCr+U; __CSALastPageName=XCOaF
   ...: cpXdhusg==; __CSALastHierarchy=L7ATLYBSXZmXj3ddzXRPF7BVVZFzs=; __CSALastReportSuiteName=0eWIC8dcnfMSQ==; __CSARedirectTags=ABOcOxeO5Rw==;  pck=0aa46f23-cc8d12f4
   ...: b2d9; __CSCookie=RVqW7dLcpCsk3wIlGmvZSVdPmNjkdGJ9+zMtfOYdMV/fQBUDLKlF01gkDTUg9IENJq+mVzOR1wbxACRCgIcBWYnPY0O83Cet4n73Fah5UvdTzbfayAEgnHsTch/OrCOSTZaK4peWy/1kXq3
   ...: fX2uHLPbrw4BgXhaZvjRUp4yRhaL+Ug2qcj6pQny6oyot+GPOBP4OgqtbzTZJv7NxykKZHKZRzjYBvBLtbOf9brrzjOihmDBGDG0Rn16jC9T8MtbUl3VKz3GojZeLTmYTCXX67oBmnGZPPtV8joGqYrVcHrSaSmL
   ...: vVeYt9ieNaiJRkSNnqZMHN0oj0XKxyeFBluQONFGvEGhw/7TKoshKQfd5oNo7A9eJ+UfEvG51iwT/3ePMd6MvzFMdj+5Fg6MIlBuFYXrwVOwIeuhFcjdas9v+bWH923AYt7rUnb99T8AX6+8cJy0/fj69AkdhG/F
   ...: TvNQrV05Lpbr5gjL5uy8N4Ng2zsoKMdgrFYalARQNM/8h0i7HhxQyx+OY6PXR0VbTGI=; ETE1=fvClmAi4/MuJaZFB+0Cac7U1k4DPA5UuABTPG9Xp+KAVSMf3ES0cJm94ok4ZwIQ1Y/AiaX1j7lf6BQpcoI9Uw
   ...: GAe9PUFnpSn3YDa0MoJ9xC7fwwPigfrd7oxdyi8nvCKs5OYcrf0zEAMiMUEM//Imb3d015qESq0aThM4W51AmI4EEDdFk2l8aqkDjAE8ZmWwhuKwT7C7xyk4Q1mdD0l3kFum4C1g2cbIaNQ5qMJ3M+DJvu7SbjVI
   ...: AZanGwrt1aZLL/1Eo1MPVEuGmMOj/p6hHtjBc; icxid=1461418-3071016; gigyaCookieNotification=acknowledged; __PublicSiteRecentSearchesCookie=UeUbHUqUtzmA==; __CSUserIbc
   ...: IDCookie=dHEe9zrPGNScOhtqfft1DC571R+670C7m6; __CSUserIbcMonikerCookie=Oiz4bVglGrhbAzQ==; __qca=P0-455503562-1461259; icxid=14612418-30873371016; s_vi=[CS]v1|2B9
   ...: 17051D1FEE-40001000FA6D[CE]; s_fid=0C6EA0A143CF-1810DF8985; dtPC=-; s_cc=true; dtLatC=54p52.5p46.5p37p4p41p55.5p3p105; dtCookie=B66FBB0F863198A2D45|VVMr1BXU3wx"
   ...: '

In [2]: body.splitlines()
Out[2]: ['2016-06-14  18:20:07    1.1.1.1 GET /origin.com/UI/Core/Images/2c.png   304 204 0   "http://www.referrer.com/CategoryPage.aspx?"    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0)" "ASP.NET_SessionId=yjumie0d5l12dl; __SessionCookie=7FKbuq3luPyu/Tz2ZKewLVMAjOtKTbLpb8zK8j0TCr+U; __CSALastPageName=XCOaFcpXdhusg==; __CSALastHierarchy=L7ATLYBSXZmXj3ddzXRPF7BVVZFzs=; __CSALastReportSuiteName=0eWIC8dcnfMSQ==; __CSARedirectTags=ABOcOxeO5Rw==;  pck=0aa46f23-cc8d12f4b2d9; __CSCookie=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; ETE1=fvClmAi4/MuJaZFB+0Cac7U1k4DPA5UuABTPG9Xp+KAVSMf3ES0cJm94ok4ZwIQ1Y/AiaX1j7lf6BQpcoI9UwGAe9PUFnpSn3YDa0MoJ9xC7fwwPigfrd7oxdyi8nvCKs5OYcrf0zEAMiMUEM//Imb3d015qESq0aThM4W51AmI4EEDdFk2l8aqkDjAE8ZmWwhuKwT7C7xyk4Q1mdD0l3kFum4C1g2cbIaNQ5qMJ3M+DJvu7SbjVIAZanGwrt1aZLL/1Eo1MPVEuGmMOj/p6hHtjBc; icxid=1461418-3071016; gigyaCookieNotification=acknowledged; __PublicSiteRecentSearchesCookie=UeUbHUqUtzmA==; __CSUserIbcIDCookie=dHEe9zrPGNScOhtqfft1DC571R+670C7m6; __CSUserIbcMonikerCookie=Oiz4bVglGrhbAzQ==; __qca=P0-455503562-1461259; icxid=14612418-30873371016; s_vi=[CS]v1|2B917051D1FEE-40001000FA6D[CE]; s_fid=0C6EA0A143CF-1810DF8985; dtPC=-; s_cc=true; dtLatC=54p52.5p46.5p37p4p41p55.5p3p105; dtCookie=B66FBB0F863198A2D45|VVMr1BXU3wx"']

In [3]: import re

In [4]: pattern = '(\d{4}[-]\d{2}[-]\d{2})\s+(\d{2}[:]\d{2}[:]\d{2})\s+(\d{1,3}[.]\d{1,3}[.]\d{1,3}[.]\d{1,3})\s+([GET|PUT|POST]+)\s+([^\s]+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+
   ...: ([^\s]+)\s+(\".*?\")\s+(\".*?\")'

In [5]: match = re.compile(pattern)

In [6]: match
Out[6]: re.compile(r'(\d{4}[-]\d{2}[-]\d{2})\s+(\d{2}[:]\d{2}[:]\d{2})\s+(\d{1,3}[.]\d{1,3}[.]\d{1,3}[.]\d{1,3})\s+([GET|PUT|POST]+)\s+([^\s]+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+([^\s]+)\s+(".*?")\s+(".*?")')



In [11]: x.groups()
Out[11]:
('2016-06-14',
 '18:20:07',
 '1.1.1.1',
 'GET',
 '/origin.com/UI/Core/Images/2c.png',
 '304',
 '204',
 '0',
 '"http://www.referrer.com/CategoryPage.aspx?"',
 '"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0)"',
 '"ASP.NET_SessionId=yjumie0d5l12dl; __SessionCookie=7FKbuq3luPyu/Tz2ZKewLVMAjOtKTbLpb8zK8j0TCr+U; __CSALastPageName=XCOaFcpXdhusg==; __CSALastHierarchy=L7ATLYBSXZmXj3ddzXRPF7BVVZFzs=; __CSALastReportSuiteName=0eWIC8dcnfMSQ==; __CSARedirectTags=ABOcOxeO5Rw==;  pck=0aa46f23-cc8d12f4b2d9; __CSCookie=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; ETE1=fvClmAi4/MuJaZFB+0Cac7U1k4DPA5UuABTPG9Xp+KAVSMf3ES0cJm94ok4ZwIQ1Y/AiaX1j7lf6BQpcoI9UwGAe9PUFnpSn3YDa0MoJ9xC7fwwPigfrd7oxdyi8nvCKs5OYcrf0zEAMiMUEM//Imb3d015qESq0aThM4W51AmI4EEDdFk2l8aqkDjAE8ZmWwhuKwT7C7xyk4Q1mdD0l3kFum4C1g2cbIaNQ5qMJ3M+DJvu7SbjVIAZanGwrt1aZLL/1Eo1MPVEuGmMOj/p6hHtjBc; icxid=1461418-3071016; gigyaCookieNotification=acknowledged; __PublicSiteRecentSearchesCookie=UeUbHUqUtzmA==; __CSUserIbcIDCookie=dHEe9zrPGNScOhtqfft1DC571R+670C7m6; __CSUserIbcMonikerCookie=Oiz4bVglGrhbAzQ==; __qca=P0-455503562-1461259; icxid=14612418-30873371016; s_vi=[CS]v1|2B917051D1FEE-40001000FA6D[CE]; s_fid=0C6EA0A143CF-1810DF8985; dtPC=-; s_cc=true; dtLatC=54p52.5p46.5p37p4p41p55.5p3p105; dtCookie=B66FBB0F863198A2D45|VVMr1BXU3wx"')
```

You can try wrapping all of it into 1 dict like this and passing that? (its a bit rough )

```
In [20]: x.groups()
Out[20]:
('2016-06-14',
 '18:20:07',
 '1.1.1.1',
 'GET',
 '/origin.com/UI/Core/Images/2c.png',
 '304',
 '204',
 '0',
 '"http://www.referrer.com/CategoryPage.aspx?"',
 '"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0)"',
 '"ASP.NET_SessionId=yjumie0d5l12dl; __SessionCookie=7FKbuq3luPyu/Tz2ZKewLVMAjOtKTbLpb8zK8j0TCr+U; __CSALastPageName=XCOaFcpXdhusg==; __CSALastHierarchy=L7ATLYBSXZmXj3ddzXRPF7BVVZFzs=; __CSALastReportSuiteName=0eWIC8dcnfMSQ==; __CSARedirectTags=ABOcOxeO5Rw==;  pck=0aa46f23-cc8d12f4b2d9; __CSCookie=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; ETE1=fvClmAi4/MuJaZFB+0Cac7U1k4DPA5UuABTPG9Xp+KAVSMf3ES0cJm94ok4ZwIQ1Y/AiaX1j7lf6BQpcoI9UwGAe9PUFnpSn3YDa0MoJ9xC7fwwPigfrd7oxdyi8nvCKs5OYcrf0zEAMiMUEM//Imb3d015qESq0aThM4W51AmI4EEDdFk2l8aqkDjAE8ZmWwhuKwT7C7xyk4Q1mdD0l3kFum4C1g2cbIaNQ5qMJ3M+DJvu7SbjVIAZanGwrt1aZLL/1Eo1MPVEuGmMOj/p6hHtjBc; icxid=1461418-3071016; gigyaCookieNotification=acknowledged; __PublicSiteRecentSearchesCookie=UeUbHUqUtzmA==; __CSUserIbcIDCookie=dHEe9zrPGNScOhtqfft1DC571R+670C7m6; __CSUserIbcMonikerCookie=Oiz4bVglGrhbAzQ==; __qca=P0-455503562-1461259; icxid=14612418-30873371016; s_vi=[CS]v1|2B917051D1FEE-40001000FA6D[CE]; s_fid=0C6EA0A143CF-1810DF8985; dtPC=-; s_cc=true; dtLatC=54p52.5p46.5p37p4p41p55.5p3p105; dtCookie=B66FBB0F863198A2D45|VVMr1BXU3wx"')

In [22]: doc = dict(zip(('date', 'time', 'client_ip', 'method', 'request', 'status_code', 'bytes', 'time_taken', 'referrer', 'user_agent', 'cookie'),x.groups()))

In [23]: doc
Out[23]:
{'bytes': '204',
 'client_ip': '1.1.1.1',
 'cookie': '"ASP.NET_SessionId=yjumie0d5l12dl; __SessionCookie=7FKbuq3luPyu/Tz2ZKewLVMAjOtKTbLpb8zK8j0TCr+U; __CSALastPageName=XCOaFcpXdhusg==; __CSALastHierarchy=L7ATLYBSXZmXj3ddzXRPF7BVVZFzs=; __CSALastReportSuiteName=0eWIC8dcnfMSQ==; __CSARedirectTags=ABOcOxeO5Rw==;  pck=0aa46f23-cc8d12f4b2d9; __CSCookie=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; ETE1=fvClmAi4/MuJaZFB+0Cac7U1k4DPA5UuABTPG9Xp+KAVSMf3ES0cJm94ok4ZwIQ1Y/AiaX1j7lf6BQpcoI9UwGAe9PUFnpSn3YDa0MoJ9xC7fwwPigfrd7oxdyi8nvCKs5OYcrf0zEAMiMUEM//Imb3d015qESq0aThM4W51AmI4EEDdFk2l8aqkDjAE8ZmWwhuKwT7C7xyk4Q1mdD0l3kFum4C1g2cbIaNQ5qMJ3M+DJvu7SbjVIAZanGwrt1aZLL/1Eo1MPVEuGmMOj/p6hHtjBc; icxid=1461418-3071016; gigyaCookieNotification=acknowledged; __PublicSiteRecentSearchesCookie=UeUbHUqUtzmA==; __CSUserIbcIDCookie=dHEe9zrPGNScOhtqfft1DC571R+670C7m6; __CSUserIbcMonikerCookie=Oiz4bVglGrhbAzQ==; __qca=P0-455503562-1461259; icxid=14612418-30873371016; s_vi=[CS]v1|2B917051D1FEE-40001000FA6D[CE]; s_fid=0C6EA0A143CF-1810DF8985; dtPC=-; s_cc=true; dtLatC=54p52.5p46.5p37p4p41p55.5p3p105; dtCookie=B66FBB0F863198A2D45|VVMr1BXU3wx"',
 'date': '2016-06-14',
 'method': 'GET',
 'referrer': '"http://www.referrer.com/CategoryPage.aspx?"',
 'request': '/origin.com/UI/Core/Images/2c.png',
 'status_code': '304',
 'time': '18:20:07',
 'time_taken': '0',
 'user_agent': '"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0)"'}

In [24]:
```